# Find commits with given ancestors

Tags: bash, git, ancestor

At one point, my git repository contains the following structure:

```
A1    A2    A3
 o-----o-----o
        \     \
         o X   o Y
B1    B2/   B3/
 o-----o-----o
        \
         o Z
C1    C2/
 o-----o
```

I'm trying to retrieve the earliest commit that is a descendant from several specified commits. The tiebreak would be the commit date. For example:

```
descendant A1 B2 -> X
descendant A2 B3 -> Y
descendant A1 C1 -> nothing
```

The merge commits may have more than two parents. I've found a lot of documentation about `git merge-base`, which does pretty much the opposite task, but can't find any function that would at least return a list of descendants that I could sort.

Comment: Git only tracks *parents* of a commit, not children. Given only `A1` and `B2`, there's no way of finding their common descendants other than checking *every* commit to see if it has `A1` and `B2` as an ancestor.

Comment: To add to @chepner’s comment, the term for this is a DAG (directed acyclic graph). The edges between each node is one way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've managed to piece together after some more research. It's ugly, it's probably *very* inefficient, but it looks like it works.

```
#!/bin/bash

common_descendants=$(git rev-list --ancestry-path --all $1.. | sort)
shift

while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
    common_descendants=$(
        echo "$common_descendants"
        | comm -12 --nocheck-order - <(
            git rev-list --ancestry-path --all $1.. | sort
        )
    )
    shift
done

git rev-list --reverse --date-order --no-walk $common_descendants | head -n 1
```

It uses `git rev-list --ancestry-path --all` to find all descendants of each requested commit in turn.
Theses lists are intersected with the help of `sort` and `comm` to obtain the list of candidate commits.
Finally, `git rev-list --ancestry-path --all` orders them by commit date, and `head -n 1` picks the oldest one.

Comment: `--ancestry-path` will get you similar results to what I suggested: here you're using `HEAD` as the point from which the enumeration runs backwards, and then also discarding commits that are neither ancestors of `HEAD` nor descendants of your limiting commit. You're excluding the specific limiting commits themselves, though, which might be the answer to the lowest common descendant.

Comment: @torek I'll have to think about it some more before it clicks. I hadn't considered that the tips could be useful to traverse the graph the right way around. Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

As [chepner commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709145/find-commits-with-given-ancestors#comment92344961_52709145), Git only has backwards pointers.  *Find descendants of commit C* must be transformed into a new and different problem, which is instead: *Find ancestors of commit T that themselves have commit C as an ancestor.*  Here *T* is a tip commit, or in your case, perhaps many tip commits—all branches, and perhaps all tags and all other references as well.

The `git rev-list` command is suited to tackling the problem.  In particular, you can have it traverse the graph from tips (descendants) to parents, but collect up the edges traversed during the process, then reverse them, using `--children`.  As [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) notes, this enables parent rewriting and history simplification.

(I think you will need to run `git rev-list --children` on whatever starting tip commits you choose, and parse its output yourself to apply additional constraints.  You can use the parents of the commits that you are searching from as stopping points, using [the `^hash^@` gitrevisions syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), to cut the graph iteration.  Note that this is really leading `^`, which is like `--not` but local instead of global, applied to `rev^@`.)